# IONIC 5 ion header not transparent with a background image in ion-content

Tags: css, ionic-framework, transparent, ionic5, ion-header

I just created a blank project with ionic 5 and added a background image for the content.
After that i modified the page.page.scss file to make the header transparent but it didn't work.

If i just pick a background color for the ion-content, that works.

Please help me.

Here is my environment :

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.12
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.12
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.12
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0
```

Capacitor:

```
   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.0
```

Utility:

```
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed
```

System:

```
   NodeJS : v14.7.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.7
   OS     : macOS Catalina
```

Here is the page SCSS code :

```
  // ion-content {--background: #f1453d !important;
  //             --color : #f1453d !important }

  ion-content {
    --background : none;
    border:none;
    background-image: url(../../assets/imgs/bckgrnd.jpg) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center bottom;
  }

  ion-toolbar {
    --background: transparent !important;
    --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
    --border-color: transparent;
    --background-color: transparent !important;
  }
}
```

HTML code :

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <div id="container">
    <strong>Ready to create an app?</strong>
    <p>Start with Ionic <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/components">UI Components</a></p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

And the result in image :

[header white but not transparent...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Et8.png)

So if someone has already had this issue or the solution, it would save me and my app from many many troubles.

thank you
Bye

Answer (score 4):

Follow the steps below to make header transparent

in variable.scss add

```
:root {
        --ion-toolbar-background:transparent;
      }
```

HTML Code

```
<ion-header class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content >
   <div >
     <ion-img class="bgr" src="../../../assets/imgs/background_doodle.png"> 
     </ion-img> 
   </div>  
</ion-content>
```

in .scss add

```
.bgr {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        object-fit: cover;
     }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar,
        *::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the ionic docs (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/header), to make your header transparent you need the attributes **mode** and **translucent** set to **ios** and **true** respectively.

For example:

```
<ion-header mode="ios" translucent="true">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title size="large">My Navigation Bar</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

As the docs also mention this would not work if the device does not support `backdrop-filter`. Also you can do away with the html binding on translucent, unless you have a variable called "true" with the boolean value true.

If this does not workout, Try getting rid of the `ion-header`.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help.
I just succeed to make the header translucent but not transparent..arghh

In the CSS file i changed the --background feature of the content and added the mode="ios" attribute in my ion-header tag :

```
  ion-content {
    --background:url(../../assets/imgs/bckgrnd.jpg)  no-repeat 100% center/cover;
    border:none;
    //background-image: url(../../assets/imgs/bckgrnd.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center bottom;
  
  }
```

```
<ion-header translucent="true" mode="ios">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

I don't know what i did wrong or if the ionic 5 has lost this feature... That would be weird and very bad...
That's why i think i did something wrong...

Here is the picture :
[Header translucent , not transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbAtb.png)

Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple "one-liner" CSS solution to add a transparent (background) image to ionic 4+ content element without having troubles with transparent child elements, like text.

```
ion-content { 
  --background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(255,255,255,0.8)),
  url("assets/background_small.png") no-repeat center center / cover; 
}
```

- --background: -- to manipulate CSS (shadow DOM) of web component
- linear-gradient(...): adds transparency to the image (0.2 in the actual example!)
- no-repeat center center / cover: stretches the image endless